# How do I use a while-statement properly?

Tags: java

My code below prints my desired ouput: `The sum is 45`.

```
int sum = 0, i = 1;
while (i < 10) {
    sum = sum + i;
    i++;
} System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Why doesn't my program work if I write this code below instead?

```
int sum = 0;
while (sum < 10) {
    sum = sum + 1;
} System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

The output becomes `The sum is 10` instead of `The sum is 45`.

Comment: Because the loop exits when the condition is no longer true.

Comment: in you case you would need to write `while(sum<45)`for it to work

Comment: Because you have written `while(sum<10)` instead of `while(i<10)`.

Comment: ah cool thanks!!!!!

Comment: because the total sum is then 10

Comment: to better understand what you are doing you can print sum every time its looping so you always get the value of sum. that might help you to understand it. also in while loop every time you loop it, it checks if the condition is still true

Comment: thanks @XtremeBaumer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by others in the comments you need to replace `while(sum<10)` by `while(sum<45)`. And to understand it you could print out the value of `sum` in the loop (actually debugging your code might be better but maybe that's a step too far right now).

```
    int sum = 0;
    while (sum<45){ // <-- this is where you went wrong
        System.out.println("sum: " + sum);
        sum = sum + 1;

    }
    System.out.println("Finished! The final sum is "+ sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because

```
while (sum < 10)
```

checks sum upto 9 so you have to adjust it to so when it reaches 9 it will be 9+1 = 10. so you have to use:

```
while (sum < 45)
```

so that when it reaches 44, 1 will be added to it and the answer will be 45.
So the code excerpt will be like:

```
int sum = 0;
while (sum < 45) { //it is 45 here instead of 10  as you had done it.
sum = sum + 1;
} System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```